# Trying to export AD with PowerShell and get the values for each ADPropertyValueCollection

Tags: active-directory, powershell

Some of my fields in my CSV file are showing up as ADPropertyValueCollection

Is there anyway to get all the values of the collection and store them into my CSV?

```
showInAddressBook
Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection
```

The code I used is

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | export-csv -path c:\temp\userexport.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Please don't do `-properties *` unless you really need every property, which you apparently don't. It takes much longer to execute if you're dragging down every property in a user.

You don't need the quotes between all of the properties in your `Select` statement. Also, you had a backtick in front of `Name`. The `::join` in the sample didn't work for me either. This works:

```
Get-ADUser jeff.besos -Properties memberof | Select Name,DisplayName,SamAccountName, @{Name='MemberOf';Expression={$_.MemberOf -join ';'}}

Name           : jeff.bezos
DisplayName    :
SamAccountName : jeff.bezos
MemberOf       : CN=!IDAMAdmins,OU=Admin Groups,OU=Domain Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=com;CN=!ExchangeAdministrators,OU=Admin Groups,OU=Domain
                Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=com
```

These days I actually recommend exporting to JSON if you have multivalued attributes you're going to reprocess later. Obviously this works if you're querying multiple users as well.

```
Get-ADUser jeff.bezos -Properties memberof | Select Name,DisplayName,SamAccountName,memberof | convertto-json -depth 100 | out-file C:\myuser.json
{
    "Name":  "jeff.bezos",
    "DisplayName":  null,
    "SamAccountName":  "jeff.bezos",
    "memberof":  [
                    "CN=!IDAMAdmins,OU=Admin Groups,OU=Domain Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=com",
                    "CN=!ExchangeAdministrators,OU=Admin Groups,OU=Domain Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=com",
                ]
}
```

Then you import JSON from file into an object (it's a PSCustomObject) and process that. PSCustomObjects are handy for slicing and dicing.

```
$user = get-content C:\myuser.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$user |fl

Name           : jeff.bezos
DisplayName    :
SamAccountName : jeff.bezos
memberof       : {CN=!IDAMAdmins,OU=Admin Groups,OU=Domain Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=com,
                CN=!ExchangeAdministrators,OU=Admin Groups,OU=Domain Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=com}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to | it to a select, and specify each property name.  For multi-valued properties, do this:

```
Get-ADUser -Properties * | `
 select SamAccountName,@{Name="ShowInAddressBook";Expression={$_.showInAddressBook -join ";"}} | `
 Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\UserExport.csv
```

Comment: Is there a way to get every multi-valued property without explicitly expressing it

Comment: Please Can you share the entire line of code that you suggested?

Comment: Get-ADUser jeff.bezos -Properties * | Select `Name','DisplayName','SamAccountName', @{Name='MemberOf';Expression={[string]::join(";", ($_.MemberOf))}} | Export-Csv C:\temp\sample.csv                      I am still geting ADPropertyValueCollection for MemberOf

Comment: @softwareisfun: Not sure why [string]::join was not working. Changed it to use the PowerShell join operator and it seems to work now.